# On Monday pull data from Friday to Sunday, on other weekdays from prior day only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query which is currently pulling all incidents from a SQL Server database which were closed on prior weekday. It's pretty neat as it's using modulo to be independent over @@DATEFIRST local settings. However I need to amend it in a way that on Mondays it gives me all incidents closed between Friday and Sunday.

Current code:

```
SELECT 
    inc.Incident_Id, inc.Close_Time
FROM 
    inc
WHERE 
    CONVERT (CHAR(10), inc.Close_Time, 126) = CONVERT (CHAR(10), (DATEADD(DAY, CASE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 
                        WHEN 1 THEN -2 
                        WHEN 2 THEN -3 
                        ELSE -1 
                        END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))),126)
```

I tried using another `CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())` before first CONVERT but it didn't work out as it looked like >= and <= (or BETWEEN & AND) are not allowed both in one condition after THEN.

To sum up it should be like this:

- On Mondays - incidents closed between Friday and Sunday
- On other weekdays - incidents closed on prior day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @from date = 
    DATEADD(day, 
      CASE datediff(d, 0, getdate()) %7
           WHEN 0 THEN -3
           WHEN 6 THEN -2
           ELSE -1
      END, getdate())

SELECT inc.Incident_Id, inc.Close_Time
FROM inc  
WHERE 
  inc.Close_Time >= @from
  AND inc.Close_Time < @to
```

Monday and Sunday will return friday and after

Tuesday to saturday will return the day before.

Comment: Sorry, I typed my request incorrectly. Sunday should provide Friday and Saturday. Also your code gives me prior and current day incidents between Tuesday and Friday. And I need only prior day on Tuesday to Friday. ">=" is good for weekends and Monday.

Comment: Thanks, this is great but would it be possible to adjust the code that on Friday, Saturday, Sunday it uses ">=" and on other days just "=" ?

Comment: Code adjusted again, note your code would result in a full table scan, this will be faster than your code because it is [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)